# Restrict keycloak OIDC login with google to a specific hosted domain

Tags: jwt, google-oauth, keycloak, google-openid

I have added an identity provider with OpenID connect V1.0 and used Google endpoints. I have provided the option ?hd=X.com(https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?hd=X.com) to restrict the login, but as per the google doc, it says HD is an optional parameter. How to validate if the token received from Google after login from keycloak perspective and restrict login?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still curious about this answer, as of KC 11.0.0 the KeyCloak server is explicit that it will validate the response from Google matches the `hd` parameter you set in KeyCloak, as seen here:

[image: Screenshot of KeyCloak Google HD parameter help text]